# Queria validar dois campos input com um botão

Tags: html, validação, input

Sou mestre de um jogo RPG e fiz um enigma com um site. Nesse enigma é descobrir dois números e depois saber se eles estão corretos e após redirecionar os jogadores pra outra página. E procurei em tudo que é canto como fazer. Alguém que sabe mais poderia me ajuda? Aqui está o source da página, e só queria saber como posso fazê-lo. Agradeço pela ajuda

(Sei que só tem html, mas se tiver um solução em javascript, jquery ou css ou que for pode, caso não tenha deixado claro.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="clock1">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="num1" maxlength="2" style="width: 65px; height: 60px; font-size: 50px;"> :
            <input type="text" id="num2" maxlength="2" style="width: 65px; height: 60px; font-size: 50px;"><br>
            <div id="num3">
            <button>Try it!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, a desvantagem de fazer validação com javascript é que se seus jogadores forem um pouco espertinhos, poderão visualizar o código fonte da página e ver os números.
Bem, mas a solução é fácil! 
Você terá que fazer uma condição, onde os 2 números sejam iguais aos números desejados. Farei com jQuery!

No exemplo, defini o número 1 como 10 e o 2 como 14!

```js
$("#validar").click(function() {
  var num1 = $("#num1").val();
  var num2 = $("#num2").val();
  if (num1 == "10" && num2 == "14") {
    alert("acertou");
    window.location.href = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/230642";
  } else {
    alert("os números estão incorretos");
    $("#num1").val("");
    $("#num2").val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>clock</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="clock1">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="num1" maxlength="2" style="width: 65px; height: 60px; font-size: 50px;"> :
      <input type="text" id="num2" maxlength="2" style="width: 65px; height: 60px; font-size: 50px;"><br>
      <div id="num3">
        <button id="validar">Try it!</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```